# How much does Hashtbl.find affect performance?

Tags: ocaml

When I measure the execution time with `Hashtbl.find` the program is 16x slower than without it. Why is that?

Note that the equivalent code in Node does not show as much difference with or without the lookup table (`Map` or `Object`) (only 3x slower)

OCaml code:

```ml
let fib =
  let table  = Hashtbl.create 1000 in
  let rec f n =
    try Hashtbl.find table n 
    with Not_found -> (
      match n with
      | 0 -> 0
      | 1 -> 1
      | n ->
          let r = f (n - 1) + f (n - 2) in
          (* Hashtbl.add table n r ; *)
          r 
    )
  in
  f
```

The `Hashtbl.add` is commented on purpose, I'm just interested in the performance cost of he Hashtable `find`.

Comment: You're comparing apples and oranges. The JS code uses a built-in data structure that is JIT-compiled and executed in a bleeding-edge VM that can probably optimize the table lookup into a simple array index lookup. An array would be a much more appropriate data structure for this in OCaml as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response @glennsl I mean I'm not really interested in comparing OCaml/js but more of the with/without `Hashtabl.find`. Is it normal that a `Hashtbl.find`--even though it's an O(1) operation--have a notable performance impact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Hashtbl.find` function is not free even when applied to an empty hash table because it computes the hash of the provided key. Since you're using a polymorphic hash table implementation, a generic (implemented in C) hash function is used. These all incur some overhead w.r.t to the default payload of a Fibonacci function, which is only three arithmetic operations (i.e., an overhead of 20x3=60 arithmetic operations).

If we will use the functorial interface to provide a more efficient hashing function, we will reduce the overhead to something that is close to x3:

```
module Table = Hashtbl.Make(struct
    type t = int
    let equal : int -> int -> bool = fun x y -> x = y [@@inline]
    let hash x = x [@@inline]
  end)

let table  = Table.create 127

let fib1 x =
  let rec f n = match n with
    | 0 -> 0
    | 1 -> 1
    | n -> match Table.find_opt table n with
      | Some x -> x
      | None ->
        let r = f (n - 1) + f (n - 2) in
        (* Hashtbl.add table n r ; *)
        r in
  f x
```

Note, that I also switched from using exceptions to the option type. Setting up exception handlers inside of a recursive function implies extra overhead on each recursive call. Basically, the `try` statement has a runtime cost.

If we will compare the running time of implementation with  hash tables (`fib1`) and without (`fib2`), we will get the following numbers (in ms, on mine 2Ghz machine, for n=32)

```
fib1: 53.3791
fib2: 18.1501
```

This gives us an overhead of x3 (6 arithmetic operations on top of the Fibonacci kernel itself), which more or less corresponds to the overhead of the modulo operation (two arithmetic operations) as well as three extra calls (the find itself, our `hash` function, and the `Array.length` function.

You can also try the hash table implementation provided by the Janestreet Core library, which is usually more efficient.